# Beginning of the end

Tags: riddle

What is at the beginning of the end and the end of time and space? This is a short riddle so I'm just filling in characters to meet the requirements for length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

> the letter e

which is

> the first letter of "end" and the last letter of "time and space"